# Can't see a json content that send with post request in python and raspberry

Tags: python, json, laravel

I try to send a json from a raspberry Pi4 to Laravel project but when I try to display the content of Json I can't see anything, only an empty square brackets []

**Python code form raspberry**: this function reads from a file and converts it into a json file and sends it to Laravel:

```
def readFile():
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/device.txt", "r") as file:
        for i in file:
            line, *lines = i.split()
            if line in mac_dict:
                mac_dict[line] += lines
            else:
                mac_dict[line] = lines
    print(mac_dict)
    print("\n")

    json_obj = json.dumps(mac_dict, indent=4)
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/mac_addr.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(json_obj)

    print(json_obj)

    ip = 'http://192.168.1.6:14000'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    req = requests.post(ip, headers=headers, data=json_obj)
```

**Laravel controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DictionaryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json($request->all());
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Laravel route api**

```
Route::get('dictionary', [DictionaryController::class, 'store'])->name('dict');
```

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNd5N.png)

How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you sending to `http://192.168.1.6:14000/api/dictionary`?

Comment: Also, `requests.post` seems to send a `POST` request, while your route is `GET`

Comment: I just changed the ip but still gives me empty square brackets. Before I was sendig to http://192.168.1.6:14000, now  http://192.168.1.6:14000/api/dictionary but the problem remains